# How to select from a list of standalone antrun targets in Maven (no binding is necessary)

Tags: export, target, maven-antrun-plugin

I have searched for a way to do this but so far no go.

I want to execute a single ant task (scp a file to a remote server). This I can do, using antrun plugin. It works, no problem. But... I want to have different targets which are selectable by specifying which one I want to execute on the maven command line.

These are standalone parts of my previous Ant build process. Not sure if Maven discourages this kind of thing but logically, I thought of defining one execution per related set of ant tasks. Something like the following:

```
         <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>id1</id>
                    <configuration>
                      <target>
                        <echo message="exporting files to server1"/>
                      </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                    <id>id2</id>
                    <configuration>
                      <target>
                        <echo message="exporting files to server2"/>
                      </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This only works if I use 'default-cli' as the id for the execution block and the second one doesn't run. (what does 'cli' even stand for?)

What is the proper way to execute a standalone set of related tasks where the tasks needn't be bound to any of the Maven life-cycles? And the set of tasks can be executed by specifying which set, you want executed, on the maven command line.

I feel as though I'm swimming upstream here and that is not a good sign. Wrong tool for the job? Perhaps the lack of a concise way to do this in Maven is telling me I should be doing things differently. Even the use of profiles seems a bit like overkill, to me. This is typically not the kind of thing one finds in the documentation but I could be wrong about that. So if anyone has some advice for me, please fire away.